# Trying to pass icon into the menu

Tags: routes

I am trying to use the icon API to pass an icon to the menu - I would use the icon menu module, but I want the icon to switch based on programmatic logic.

Here's what I have so far:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  global $user;
  $icon = theme('icon', array('bundle' => "fontawesome", 'icon' => "envelope"));
  $items = array();
  $items['user/' . $user->uid . '/messages'] = array(
    'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
    'title callback' => FALSE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
    'title' => $icon . t('Messages'),
    'page callback' => 'views_embed_view',
    'page arguments' => array('message_private', 'page_1'),
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'views'),
    'file' => 'views.module',
        'options' => array('attributes' => array(
       'html' => true 
       )),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

However this just seems to get the escaped icon HTML in the menu.

How do I get the actual item from the icon API?

Is there some way to tell hook_menu to pass everything as it is?

Answer (score 0):

by [`hook_menu`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) you are just registering a path to Drupal.

> Define menu items and page callbacks.

To get this printed with icon you can try contributed modules like

1. [Menu Icons](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_icons)
2. [Icon API](https://www.drupal.org/project/icon)

**Icon API module is able to apply your programmatic logic**